# Check is an asset (GPS route) has been on restricted road

Tags: gps, routing, geofencing

If I have GPS route for an asset and want to cross check the position of the asset against (pre-defined) "illegal" routes to have taken (series of GPS decimal), what might be a reasonable approach? My issue is similar to that of geofencing (triggers when an asset goes AWOL), but the restricted space is not a polygon representing forbidden territory, but multiple specific routes (in this case a route is the combination of a series of connected "illegal" GPS positions).

Answer (score -1):

I propose to use [Map Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching) for the GPS signals, e.g. via [GraphHopper](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching) (Please note that I'm one of its authors).

And then you compare the segments to the one of one (or more) illegal route (either use edgeIds or GPS coordinates)